# javascript css framework

Tags: javascript, css, frameworks

Which is the best open source javascript css framework to implement?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JavaScript CSS framework, however,  there are JavaScript frameworks which have methods for CSS manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

in my opinion

It is **light weight** when compared to other javascript frameworks.

More **plugins** available.

Documentation is good.

Community base is large.

Comment: jQuery doesnt have much widgets

Comment: For manipulating DOM in diff ways. JQuery stands apart.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently discovered [Uzie](http://www.uize.com/)
I'm not saying that it's the best, but you should take a look at it.

Comment: It is good. is this opensource?

Comment: As it's said at the "Key Features":
UIZE is open source.
UIZE is free to use (distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License).
UIZE does not extend native objects, and supports interoperability with other libraries that adhere to this principle
UIZE is in active development, by a team of experienced programmers, and is used on zazzle.com - a high profile, consumer facing, e-commerce Web site.
UIZE is server agnostic - so you can use it with any choice of server language and platform, including Java (Apache TomCat), C# (IIS / ASP.NET), [...]